# Using ProcessBuilder to find version of Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to use Java to find out the versions of Java installed on a machine. I have:

```
List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
commands.add("java.exe");
commands.add("-version");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_45\\bin"));
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

However, when this is run, the while loop is never executed as the stdInput is empty. If I take out the `commands.add("-version")`, it will get the input that is output when running "java.exe" command on command line, so it seems adding the `-version` arguement is causing issues and this also indicates that the directory and java.exe commands are correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189192/programmatically-determine-what-jdk-jres-are-installed-on-my-box) help?

Comment: Nope, refer to @Copeg question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of `java -version` is sent to the error stream - reading from that stream should result in the proper output:

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

Alternatively, you can call `redirectErrorStream(true)` to merge the Input and Error streams. If you just wish to just print to the command line, you can use `inheritIO` on the ProcessBuilder.

The currently running java version can be found without the need for a `ProcessBuilder` by retrieving the appropriate [System property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

Comment: I am writing something that gets all versions of Java installed on machines, so I cannot use this method. I need to recursively look in well known locations and run "java.exe -version"

Comment: Ahh there it is, thank you... why would that be sent to error stream??

Answer (score 1):

`java -version` prints to stderr. Try using:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands).redirectErrorStream(true);
```

That will put stderr in the same stream as stdout and the rest of your code can look as it does now.